# Using mutate across to enforce class of columns matching a certain name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list column of tibbles, and in some of them I want to enforce that a column with a certain name, is a character vector. I've tried to do this with tidyverse but I'm not getting any joy.

Here's a minimal example:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

data <- list(
  tibble(A = 1:10, B = 1:10, C = 1:10),
  tibble(A = 1:10, "Direct written by (3)" = 1:10, C = 1:10),
  tibble(A = 1:10, B = 1:10, C = 1:10)
)

newData <- purrr::map(data, function(dataTable){
  mutate(dataTable, across(matches("Direct written by (3)"), ~as.character(.x)))
})
```

It seems like the above should do it, but it does not:

```
> str(data)
List of 3
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ B: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A                    : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ Direct written by (3): int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C                    : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ B: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> str(newData)
List of 3
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ B: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A                    : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ Direct written by (3): int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C                    : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ B: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ C: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How can I acheive the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `contains` instead of `matches` as there are characters (`()`) which may be evaluated in regex mode as metacharacters (or else have to either escape (`\\`) or wrap with `fixed`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(data, ~ .x %>% 
   mutate(across(contains("Direct written by (3)"), 
        as.character)))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       A `Direct written by (3)`     C
   <int> <chr>                   <int>
 1     1 1                           1
 2     2 2                           2
 3     3 3                           3
 4     4 4                           4
 5     5 5                           5
 6     6 6                           6
 7     7 7                           7
 8     8 8                           8
 9     9 9                           9
10    10 10                         10

[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10
```

---

`matches` with `fixed`

```
map(data, ~ .x %>% 
   mutate(across(matches(fixed("Direct written by (3)")), 
        as.character)))
```

Comment: `any_of()` or `all_of()` would be even better/more general when using a full, exact column name.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, if the column name is not a substring.